# Home cooked diets for dogs: is it fine to freeze it?

Tags: dogs, diet

I'm still trying to find my way about dogs' food.

I'm considering to start with:

1. Home cooked food treats for training (bite sized, easy to carry with me, eg. pieces of boiled chicken without bones)
2. Home cooked meals for Kongs (easy to be put in the Kong, would replace a few meals a week)

I'm not planning to cook for the dog (nor for me...) everyday, so the question is: **can these be cooked once a week and then frozen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes absolutely. I tend to save left over meats from my meals and freeze those for later use too. Here are a few that work well: chicken breast, steak/roast, liver, chicken hearts. And cutting up string cheese works really well and doesn't need to be frozen. You can also cut up turkey or all beef hotdogs and use those but use that sparingly as they are high in sodium and low in things that are "good for you" where the other things listed here have good nutritional value. For lower level treats like what you would want to mix in and leave in a Kong you can use frozen veggies like carrots and peas. Avoid anything with onion... if it is left overs cooked with them is ok but don't include the actual onion in what you give your dog.